# xp_cmdshell access in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I had inherited a stored procedure from a colleague that uses the `xp_cmdshell` within it. In order to enable this feature for the particular login, I need to run the following commands to enable it.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

I had added sysadmin server role access to this particular login, and running this stored procedure require sysadmin access so far.

We had granted this particular user with sysadmin access in the development SQL Server. As we migrate the stored procedure to production environment, DBA had concerns there is too much privilege for this user in production environment.

Is there any way we can continue to run the stored procedure with this login without the sysadmin access in the production environment?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Search for xp_cmdshell proxy account.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what the stored procedure does that requires `xp_cmdshell`, or why this has to be done in SQL Server in the first place. Usually, there are much better approaches.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The stored procedure tries to perform basic file IO operation to move, copy, delete files to a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.  I am continuing the comment here as I need markup for the sample code.

The stored procedure tries to perform basic file IO operation to move, copy, delete files to a network drive.

```
    e.g.   exec @ret_val = master..xp_cmdshell @stmt, no_output @stmt 
    @stmt can be "copy //hostname/mapdrive/subdirectory/somefile //hostname/mapped directory" using sharing mechanism.
   or create a subdirectory.  
    e.g. select @stmt = 'md '+@pri_path
```

I believe they perform this using stored procedure so they can contain all the file I/O operation within the stored procedure.

As for the xp_cmd_shell_proxy_account, I found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190359.aspx. Based on my interpretation, we are providing a windows login username and password to the sql server to gain access to a shell.  Am I correct?

Thanks.